# How to parse the value 'PC' from contains(Name,'PC') using javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I need to parse the API request key parameter to get the value from it: 
$filter=contains(Name,'PC'). Actually, the value of the parameter is "contains(Name,'PC')", so I need to parse only that part. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: There's lots of string functionality available to you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: `"contains(Name,'PC')".split("Name,'").pop().split("'")[0]`

Comment: I need to get the value 'PC' from the filter parameter, to compare it with the response json in Postman.
So I use 
pm.expect(Groups[key].Name).to.include(<I NEED TO ENTER THE ANSWER HERE>);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses javascript regex **/^contains(Name, '(\w+)')$/**.

If expression match the value will be extracted.

Examples:

Your case with PC value:

```
"contains(Name, 'PC')".match(/^contains\(Name, '(\w+)'\)$/)[1]
```

*output **PC***

Others values...

```
"contains(Name, 'MacOs')".match(/^contains\(Name, '(\w+)'\)$/)[1]
```

*output **MacOs***

For more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions